# Mathematica; NDSolve; Can I use InterpolatingFunction as initial conditions?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The questions arises because I want to use the solution of one PDE as initial condition to solve another. Since in NDSolve, the solution is given by InterpolatingFunction, I have to use InterpolatingFunction in the second PDE. Is this possible? Why it takes my computer to run it forever?
My code:

```
(*********************Parameters********************)
\[Gamma] = 10^(-5); 
T = 500; 
tm = -250; 
\[Sigma] = 100; 
L = 1; 
L0 = -(L/2); 
L1 = L0 + L; 
c = 29.979; 
\[Omega] = 1.32949/10^8; 
\[Eta] = 1539.1; 
\[Mu] = 6.27; 
\[Beta] = 0.1334; 
k = 40895.3; 

(*********************1st PDE********************)
solS = NDSolve[{D[sS[z, t], t] == (-(\[Gamma] + I*\[Beta]*z))*sS[z, t]-I*\[Omega]*aS[z, t], 
D[aS[z, t], z] + (1/c)*D[aS[z, t], t] == (-I)*\[Eta]*k*sS[z, t], sS[z, -T] == 0, 
aS[z, -T] == E^(-((-T - tm)^2/(2*\[Sigma]^2))), 
aS[L0, t] == E^(-((t - tm)^2/(2*\[Sigma]^2)))}, {sS, aS}, {z, L0, L1}, {t, -T, 0}, 
MaxSteps -> Infinity]

(*************take the result and plot**************)
iniR = solS[[1]][[1]][[2]]
Plot3D[Re[iniR[z, t]], {z, L0, L1}, {t, -T, 0}, PlotRange -> All]

(***********2nd PDE, with the 1st result as ini. con.***********)
solR = NDSolve[{D[sR[z, t], t] == (-(\[Gamma] - I*\[Beta]*z))*sR[z, t] - I*\[Omega]*aR[z, t], 
D[aR[z, t], z] + (1/c)*D[aR[z, t], t] == (-I)*\[Eta]*k*sR[z, t], 
sR[z, 0] == iniR[z, 0], aR[z, 0] == 0, aR[L0, t] == 0}, {sR, aR}, {z, L0, L1}, 
{t, 0, T}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

Comment: In principle, yes, you can use the result of one PDE to solve another. I don't know how it is done in Mathematica, but if your intention is to do this, one usually manages to have the same grid (or more generally the same representation) for both PDEs to avoid interpolation.

Comment: Alexandre: Thank you. Could you be more specific about "to have the same grid (or more generally the same representation) for both PDEs to avoid interpolation"? You mean change my equation? How do I realize that in Mathematica?

Comment: This is related to [this physicsforums thread](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=544396).

Comment: @user1019155: I think your problem here is that you don't have enough access to the underlying numerical scheme. This is not desirable here. You'd want the raw output of the scheme (not the interpolating function) to plug into the second solver. Unfortunately, I don't know Mathematica enough to be able to help you.

Comment: @AlexandreC: The `InterpolationFunction` output by the first PDE is actually desirable within Mathematica. For the given set of grid points in `z` and `t`, it provides the best presentation possible.

Answer (score 0):

First off: Yes you can use interpolation functions. There's nothing wrong with that. For Mathematica, an `InterpolatingFunction` merely has an interpolating polynomial being applied over the set of points to produce intermediary points. In fact, the `InterpolatingFunction` produced is the most accurate representation you can use.

The reason why your calculation is taking "forever" is because you set `MaxSteps` to infinity.

It's not an issue of using an interpolating function. It's more of an issue that the simulation you're doing is numerically sensitive. By specifying `MaxSteps->Infinity`, you're telling Mathematica to take as much time as it needs to produce a solution.

In the process of doing so, it's probably reducing the step size to something absurdly tiny, say 10^-6, just to get numerically stable results. It's only doing that because of the `MaxSteps->Infinity` setting. If you remove this, it can actually produce a solution but it'll warn you that the solution is poor.

You even get an error from Mathematica complaining that the solution will be bad:

> NDSolve::eerr: Warning: Scaled local spatial error estimate of
>   559.4348244417077`at t = 3.808844111947534` in the direction of independent variable z is much greater than prescribed error
>   tolerance. Grid spacing with 25 points may be too large to achieve the
>   desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or you
>   may want to specify a smaller grid spacing using the MaxStepSize or
>   MinPoints method options. >>